# iframe showing only a particular part

Tags: html, css, image, iframe

I am working on iframes, and I need to show only a particular portion of the page.

I want to display only this part of the blog.

http://s17.postimg.org/ickav5d33/pic.png

[This is the actual page of the blog.](http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html)

This is my code:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;"> 
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: -185px; height: 859px; margin-top: -533px; width: 926px;"> 
</iframe> 
</div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnmteg76/)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify something... what is the particular portion you want to show? Are you saying the iframe isn't positioning its content as you want? Or are you saying you don't want the extra white space around your content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you just need to tweak your inline CSS a bit. For example:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid rgb(201, 0, 1); overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; width: 675px;"> 
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html" style="border: 0px none; margin-left: 13px; height: 954px; margin-top: -422px; width: 660px;"> 
</iframe> 
</div>
```

This appears to match the picture you provided.

I changed the margin-left, margin-top, and width of the iframe. I also changed the div's max-width to a simple width with a different value.

I figured the values for all these using Firebug. I highly recommend familiarizing yourself with browser developer tools such as that (all modern browsers include some kind of "developer tools" these days) that let you play with these things "live" until you find the tweaked CSS you like.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cnmteg76/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cnmteg76/3/show   I m getting a scroll bar at the right hand side.how to remove it?

Comment: That scroll bar is not because of your iframe, it's because jsfiddle.net's "show" page adds its own iframe and scrollbars automatically. When you implement the above source code on its own page outside of jsfiddle, there shouldn't be any scroll bars.

If scrollbars still appear then of course, let us know. :) But in your link, those bars are outside of our control. They're jsfiddle's.

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to any portion of a page with a link if the element has an id attrib. IE http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html#boxB links to boxB scroll position any yes that can be used in as an iframe URL.

div id=post-body-2265336028782673534 is the closest element with an ID attrib. Unfortunately there are 10 br elements under this position and not html element with an ID closer. http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html#post-body-2265336028782673534

If you can change the source page, place an id attrib in the font tag element (ID="linkanchor"). Link to the page, using the iframe, with a hash tag link ... http://teamiwatefsu.blogspot.com/2014/09/jsfiddle-demo-div-display-inline-block.html#linkanchor